# Is there a "clean" way to pass a large number (say, 20+) arguments to a class constructor?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have some class, `myClass`, with a class constructor that takes 20 arguments, and simply assigns the passed values to class variables. Here's a smaller example, in case that's not clear

```
class myClass{

    float a, b, c;

    public:
       myClass(float _a, float _b, float _c) : a(_a), b(_b), c(_c) {}

};
```

Is there a "cleaner" and/or more efficient way to do this? Perhaps a best practice? I've thought about simply passing a `vector<float>`, something like this:

```
class myClass{
    vector<float> args;
    
    public:
        myClass(vector<float> _args){ args = _args; }
};
```

However, since I'm working with so many parameters, it later becomes confusing. For example, in some method I'm suddenly working with `args[13]` as opposed to something more descriptive, like `numDays`. I perform a lot of math on these numbers, so it's important that everything is very clear and concise.

Comment: a) don't do it. If you class needs 20 parameters then you are not following the single responsibility principle, meaning you have a design issue, passing the parameters to the constructor is only a symptom of that. b) use an array or vector

Comment: Use data classes.

Comment: you can "wrap" the arguments in structs, if there are some relations on them (ex: for a Software Engener you should have for example a struct Person for personal data, a struct Education for the educations of that person, and so on)

Comment: btw you should use the member initializer list instead of assigning in the constructors body

Comment: context is missing to suggest something cleaner. What are those parameters? Are there parameters that belong together? Can you identify parts of the maths that only works on a subset of the parameters?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Thanks for the suggestion. Is there an important difference between using the member initialzer list and assigning in the body of the constructor? As I understand it, the two are virtually (if not precisely) identical.

Comment: @Berto99 I think this is likely the best answer.

Comment: @KeithMadison they are not identical. Assigning in the body is not initialization. Members are initialized before the body of the constructor is executed. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

Comment: A builder pattern maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A) The builder pattern**

You can use the builder pattern. I am not going to strictly follow the pattern. For official details I refer you to the numerous available online resources on design patterns.  The basic idea is that you enable the caller to write instead of

```
MonsterClass m{ a,b,c, ....... d,e,f };
```

the nicer

```
auto m = MonsterBuilder{}.set_a(a).set_b(b). .... set_f(f);
```

Advantage: Named parameters. C++ does not have named parameters, the builder pattern is a way to emulate them.

In your case it could be implemented as follows:

```
#include<iostream>

struct myClass{

    float a, b, c;

    myClass(float a, float b, float c) : a(a),b(b),c(c) 
    {}                               //^^ use the initializer list

    void print(){    // added for testing
        std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << "\n";
    }
};

struct myClassBuilder {
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
    myClassBuilder& set_a(float x){ a = x; return *this; }
    myClassBuilder& set_b(float x){ b = x; return *this; }
    myClassBuilder& set_c(float x){ c = x; return *this; }
    operator myClass(){
        return myClass(a,b,c);
    }
    myClass build() {
        return *this;
    }
};


int main() {
    auto m1 = myClassBuilder{}.set_a(1).set_b(2).set_c(3).build();
    m1.print();
    
    myClass m2 = myClassBuilder{}.set_a(1).set_b(2).set_c(3);
    m2.print();
}
```

The `operator myClass` allows to convert the builder to the actual object (by calling the constructor). The `build` method is needed when you want to use `auto`. [Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Tvreco). Of course you should use meaningful names, `a,b,c..` is just as good as using an array and index.

**B) Fix the design**

Consider the single responsibility principle. If your class does too much at once then you have more severe problems than getting the parameters into the constructor in a "nice" way. For example, it is impossible to get acceptable test coverage for something that takes 20+ inputs.

Suppose 3 of the 20+ parameters are `numDays`, `numMonth` and `numYears`. Then you should group them together:

```
struct date_counter {
    int numDays;
    int numMonth;
    int numYears;
};
```

If on the other hand, the numbers are really just a bunch of numbers, then use a container.

Comment: *"C++ does not have named parameters"*, not natively, but there are ways to emulate them :) for [example](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/12/14/named-arguments-cpp/).

Answer (score 1):

You could write a class that has all these fields and just pass the class. Then, you can do yourClass.numDays and such.

Comment: and that class has a constructor that takes 20 parameters ?  :P

Comment: If you need 20 variables you need to enter them somehow, I can't figure away to get around that. Just trying to make it look cleaner than passing individual variables and making the names easier to read than an array. Can't get around variable creation, you need as many as you need.

Comment: @idclev463035818 you can have a class with 20 different setter functions, each of which returns a reference to the object so you can daisy chain them.  `args().a(10).b(20).c(30)`.

Comment: @MarkRansom the builder pattern if I remember correctly. I dislike it, because it makes you write lots of boilerplate to get nothing but some syntactic sugar but otherwise nothing that a plain old struct cannot do as well. The actual problem (a flaw in the design) isnt solved by adding the sugar, though ymmv

Comment: @idclev463035818 it might not be a great solution, but it beats calling a function with 20 parameters that you probably won't remember the order of.  I don't think I've ever actually used this pattern myself.

Answer (score -3):

I think your class has a lot of responsibilities. The **SOLID's** principles, more specifically, **Single responsability's** principle specify that one class should do only one thing and like you need a constructor which takes 20 arguments, i guess your class is an all-in-one.

Comment: The SRP says a class should only have *one reason to change*, with that reason coming from the application domain. That doesn’t mean it should only do one thing. And the number of constructor parameters tells you nothing about the SRP. – Although 20 params *do* hint at some kind of design problem somewhere in the vicinity of that class.